# Sprite Kit delay on runAction completion?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, a-star

I'm building a game with Sprite Kit that implements A* Pathfinding. I'm using a grid system (blocks) that the character uses to calculate the path, it works great. My problem is the animation.

I'm using a NSMutableArray to hold the steps and removes a step each time the move has been completed (runAction completion). It works but the animation freezes for a microsecond between completion and the new move making it look "choppy", its not a smooth move...

I've tried a lot of things and the only thing that works is to change the duration to about 1.5 seconds to move 32px (its going to be a sloooooow game ;) ). When I want the duration I need (0.7) the problem is there.

I really hope someone can help me.

Here is some code:

```
-(void)animateChar {

    self.currentStepAction = nil;

    if (self.pendingMove != nil) {
        tileMap *moveTarget = pendingMove;
        self.pendingMove = nil;
        self.shortestPath = nil;
        [self moveToward:moveTarget];
        return;
    }

    if (self.shortestPath == nil) {
        return;
    }


    // WE HAVE REACHED OUR BLOCK! CHECK IF ITS CLICKED OR STROLLING
    if ([self.shortestPath count] == 0) {

        self.shortestPath = nil;
        self.moving = FALSE;
        self.strolling = FALSE;

        if (self.minionBlock) {
            CGPoint diff = ccpSub(self.minionBlock.position, self.parentBlock.position);
            if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
                if (diff.x > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceRight speed:0.3]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceLeft speed:0.3]; }
            } else {
                if (diff.y > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceUp speed:0.3]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceDown speed:0.3]; }
            }

            // SET TIMER FOR REMOVING THE BLOCK. EVERY 0.5 SECONDS IT REMOVES X ENDURANCE.
            self.blockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(pickBlock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        } else {

            [self setMinionBusy:FALSE];
            [self runAnimation:_waiting speed:0.3];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(selectRandBlockAndMove) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }

        return;
    }

    ShortestPathStep *s = [self.shortestPath objectAtIndex:0];

    // CHECK HOLE ON NEXT DOWN
    tileMap *checkHole = [s.theBlock getNeighbor:1];

    if ([checkHole isBlockType] == 2) { // THERE IS A HOLE, WE CANT REACH!

        if ([_scene getRecentBlock] == self.minionBlock) { [_scene controlHud:1]; }

        [self removeBlockBar];
        [self.minionBlock setOccupied:FALSE];
        self.minionBlock = nil;
        self.currentStepAction = nil;
        self.pendingMove = nil;
        self.shortestPath = nil;
        [self runAnimation:_waiting speed:0.3];
        [self addBubble:1];

        if (!self.stuck) {
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(selectRandBlockAndMove) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }

        return;
    }

    CGPoint futurePosition = s.theBlock.position;
    CGPoint currentPosition = self.parentBlock.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(futurePosition, currentPosition);

    if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
        if (diff.x > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceRight speed:0.2]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceLeft speed:0.2]; }
     } else {
        if (diff.y > 0) { [self runAnimation:_faceUp speed:0.2]; } else { [self runAnimation:_faceUp speed:0.2]; }
    }

    self.parentBlock = s.theBlock;

    currentStepAction = [SKAction moveTo:s.theBlock.position duration:1.2];

    [self runAction:currentStepAction completion:^{
        [self animateChar];
    }];

    [self.shortestPath removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: No one that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try performing the completion as an animation sequence:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[currentStepAction,
                                    [SKAction runBlock:^{ [self animateChar]; }]
                                    ]]];
```

Also this will not call `animateChar` when the SKAction is aborted while animating.

Comment: Interesting :) im going to try this tomorrow and see if it works. Ill be back.

Comment: Its so weird. It still makes this small pause when it has arrived and when it should move again. Ive tried to remove code that is not relevant but it still make the pause..

Comment: So this answer did not work for you? It is checked, but then in your comment you say it did not stop the stutter.